# read stream into image control error in uri path

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, ftp

Hey trying to read stream into image control can any one help also I have some errors in my handler page.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string PhotoPath;

    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex];

    PhotoPath = row.Cells[5].Text;
    PhotoPath = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(PhotoPath);

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
        WebRequest.Create(PhotoPath);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
            request.GetResponse();
    Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    // want to output to image control upon selection of gridview
    //using (System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(resStream))
    //{
    //    img.Save("temp.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    //}

}
```

}

I get the error Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uriString

```
public class GetImage : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        {
        string PhotoPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["PhotoPath"];
        PhotoPath = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(PhotoPath);


     FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(PhotoPath)); 
// error is here -------------------
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;    
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Administrator", "commando");

        try
        {
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];

            int i = 0;
            MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();

            do
            {

                i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                mStream.Write(bytes, 0, i);
            } while (i != 0);

            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ClearHeaders();
            context.Response.ClearContent();
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(mStream.GetBuffer());

        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {

            //throw new Exception("Unable to locate or access your file.\\nPlease try a different file.");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("An error occurred: " + ex);

        }

    }
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It seems that your PhotoPath variable is null or is not a valid uri string. can you show it's value please?

Comment: You should not call `UrlDecode`, and you should use the `context` parameter.

Comment: its value is set in my database but when I load my site i get the error upon loading not upon selection. I would understand if it did it upon selection. The photopath is stored in my gridview looks like this ftp: //192.168.1.17/Image.jpg

Comment: You need to learn the basics of HTML and HTTP.  Until you do, we probably can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained earlier, you need to set the URL in the `<img>` tag to include the `PhotoPath` in the querystring.

Comment: Please show an example because that makes no sense. Photopath is the path + image name e.g ftp:/ /192.168.1.17/Image.jpg

Comment: @Garrith: Wrong.  It does make sense.  For example: `<img src="/FtpForwarder.ashx?PhotoPath=/path/to/ftp/file" />`. You need to learn the basics of HTML and HTTP, and probably ASP.Net.

Comment: so <img src="/FtpForwarder.ashx?ftp: //192.168.1.2/image.jpg=/path/to/ftp/file" />

Comment: im using visual studio 2010 '        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" DescriptionUrl="~/GetImage.ashx" 
            Height="264px" ImageUrl="~/GetImage.ashx" Width="302px" />'

Comment: @Garrith: As I said 5 times, _you need to set the URL in the tag to include the PhotoPath in the querystring._  For example:  `<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="264px" Width="302px" ImageUrl="<%# "~/GetImage.ashx?PhotoPath=" + Server.UrlEncode(something) %>" />`

Comment: what is the something? ftp ://ipaddress/path ?

Comment: @Garrith: The `something` is an expression that gets the path for the current row.

Comment: ok i obviously cant get this to work, is there an easyier way to do this? cant I just do a ftp download in my gridview upon selection and send that info to an image control?

Comment: @Garrith: No.  This is the only (sane) way to do it.

Comment: If you really wanted to, you could download the images from FTP to the server's local disk, then set image URLs that point to the new file.  That would be insane.  Also,  you probably wouldn't be able to do that, either.